# Xamarin in VS - Add References shows no packages

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a Xamarin.Android app and need to export a field. I went to the Add References dialog  to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll but there are no packages in the list there. Everything I'm seeing suggests that there should be a number of assemblies available to reference. I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 RC 4, Xamarin 4.3.0.664, and Xamarin.Android 7.1.0.31. I have attempted a full reinstall as well as trying to find the Mono location on disk with no results. How might I get this list to populate?

[image: Screenshot of empty list from Visual Studio]

Comment: Is there a reason you're on the RC version rather than the released version?

Comment: No real reason, I just haven't had downtime for the upgrade yet. The reinstall was before the release, fyi

Comment: You'll want to check `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\{VERSION NUMBER}\Mono.Android.Export.dll`

To ensure you have the dlls. I would highly advise to use a stable VS build and not an RC.

Comment: Thanks, that assembly was there so I can move on for now, will close (or mark as answered) if upgrading to stable fixes it.

Comment: For future readers, this seems to be an issue specific to VS 2017 RC, upgrading to the release version of VS 2017 fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Mono.Android.Export.dll` in your Visual Studio / Xamarin installation:

**Example Path(Enterprise version):**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Micro‌​soft\Framework\MonoA‌​ndroid\{VERSION NUMBER}\Mono.Android.Export.dll
```

These seem to pickup just fine on the latest stable release of VS 2017.